# Field empty and cancel post to database

Tags: php, validation

I'm still beginner and still confused what to add on the code.. I have a form and I want to validate it some errors, for example. field empty.. So..

Do I have to add '**else**' or mysql_error?

```
$post = isset($_REQUEST['post']) ? $_REQUEST['post'] : null;
    if (empty($post))
    {
        echo "<p class=\"info\">The post field is empty</p>";
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
if (empty($_REQUEST['post'])) {
die("The Post field is empty.");
} else {
// Write to the database
}
```

a `mysql_error()`, on the other part, will be useful to debug if anything goes wrong when writing to the database.

Comment: That method really works for me now. But what can I do if I want to prevent the same name? Can you lead me there?

Comment: The best thing to prevent the same name is to add a unique index to your database: `ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE(username)`, assuming your table is called `users` and your name field is called `username`.

Comment: Great!! I'm going to try that! :)